# Why Set implementations don't store just keys?

Tags: java, set, key-value

I know Set uses implementation of Map<K,V>, where Set elements are **keys**. But what happens with **values**? They use `private static final Object PRESENT = new Object()` as **constant value** for each **key**.

Cool. But why? That means for each key we will store value we will never use, just so we can reuse implementation of Map? Why? Couldn't they just make Key implementation? And is that constant ever used or it just 'sits' there?

Comment: Do you mean `HashSet`, and if so _which implementation specifically_?

Comment: Yes, you can point to HashSet, its almost the same for others. They all use Map to store keys..

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in implementation, if you can see add method of HashSet returning boolean.

The `add` method calls `put(key, PRESENT)` on the internal `HashMap`.  The `remove` method calls `remove(key)` on the internal `HashMap`, but it must return a `boolean` indicating whether the key was present.  If `null` were stored as the value, then the `HashSet` would need to call `containsKey` first, then `remove`, to determine if the key was present -- additional overhead.  Here, there is only the memory overhead of one `Object`, which is quite minimal.

```
public boolean add(E e)
{
        return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

For each potential 'place' that can hold an entry in the HashSet, it must be possible to tell whether that place is occupied or not.

If you want to support a key value of null, as indeed HashSet does, then you can't use key=null as the "not used" indicator. Since you need to use key.equals() to find an object in the set, you can't have a special key object that might accidentally be equal to (not identical to) an actual key.

Thus you need a separate flag apart from the key to say whether the 'place' is occupied.  This might as well be an object reference as anything else; then you can reuse the Map implementation.

Comment: Not quite.  To make a `HashSet` all you need to do is hash the `key`. You would look up a `key` the same way for a `set` as you would for a `map`. No value is actually needed to find the key. `HashSet` uses `HashMap` simply because it's easier to reuse `HashMap's` methods then rewriting the code.

Comment: Suppose in my HashSet implementation my buckets are an array (or ArrayList) of T.  I want to add the value 'null' to my HashSet.  The implementation computes the hash of null, which selects a particular bucket.  Now, how do you know if 'null' is already in the bucket?   What would an empty bucket contain?

Comment: The empty bucket would contain null.  However, you're value of null that you wanted to put in the set could be say a private static instance of `Object()` that no one else knows about but the implementation uses to represent null.  And if you want to to see if the set contained a null, the implementation would check for that particular `object`.

Comment: I guess you could do that, but then 'contains()' would have to find an element that equals the object being looked for, but which was != the private object.

Comment: I concede.  I will retract this answer.